# Relation between $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ norms

Tags: normed-spaces

Why does the following statement hold for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

$\|x\|_1\le\sqrt{d}~\|x\|_2$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$. Then $\|x\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots+|x_n|$, $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_d^2}$.

Using inequality between arithmetic and quadratic mean:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_d^2}{d}}\geqslant \frac{|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots+|x_d|}{d}
$$
or
$$
\|x\|_2\geqslant \frac{\|x\|_1}{\sqrt{d}},
$$
as asked.

**Remark:** to prove the QM-AM inequality we can observe that
$$
\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_d^2}{d}-\left(\frac{|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots+|x_d|}{d}\right)^2=\frac{1}{d^2}\cdot \sum_{i<j} (|x_i|-|x_j|)^2\geqslant 0
$$

Comment: I do not know if I can agree with the remark as an equality. Take. 1,2,3 as an example where you do not get 1/d^2 so 14/3 - 36/9=(14-12)/3=2/3

Comment: $(1^2+2^2+3^2)/3=14/3$, $(1+2+3)/3=2$, $(1-2)^2+(1-3)^2+(2-3)^2=6$, $14/3-4=2/3=6/9$. What's wrong? :)

Comment: It isn't 1/9 as implied by the remark section. As I said I do not agree with strict equality

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you. When $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=3$ the equality holds. To prove it in general case you can just open the brackets and check that the coefficients of the $x_i^2$ and $x_ix_j$ are the same

Comment: Never mind the display I am using had multiple lines and I couldn't distinguish the dot as a period from multiplication